# DataTable footer callback with remove formatting

Tags: javascript, datatables, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel (v8) blade and DataTable.Js
I have table and there are two column with floating datas like "24 000, 00 USD". I have to show total of this column data for per page and for all data. But my code displaying incorrect result.
It seems I have to delete spaces and "USZ" and "USD" letters from data then change "," floating symbol to ".".

Please help me solve this problem.

[image: Image of table]

Here is JS code at blade

```
 $("#kvit_date1, #kvit_date2").flatpickr({dateFormat: "Y-m-d"});

    //DataTables
    var table = $('#docsTable').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        searching: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        ordering: true,
        order: [[ 1, 'desc' ]],
        rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: 3
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel', 'print', 'pdf'
        ],
        footer: true,
        initComplete: function() {
            $('.buttons-copy').html('<i class="far fa-copy" />')
            $('.buttons-csv').html('<i class="far fa-file-csv" />')
            $('.buttons-excel').html('<i class="far fa-file-excel" />')
            $('.buttons-pdf').html('<i class="far fa-file-pdf" />')
            $('.buttons-print').html('<i class="fa fa-print" />')
        },
        language: {
            "lengthMenu": "Sahifada _MENU_ ta ma`lumot ko`rsat",
            "zeroRecords": "Xech narsa topilmadi uzr!",
            "info": "_PAGE_ sahifa, jami _PAGES_ sahifa",
            "infoEmpty": "Ma'lumotlar mavjud emas",
            "infoFiltered": "(_MAX_ ta malumot filtrlangan)",
            "search": "Izlash"
        },
        drawCallback: function () {
            var api = this.api();

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {

                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    parseFloat(i.replace(/'UZS', 'USD','/g, '.'))*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            totalUZS = api
                .column( 6 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Total over all pages
            totalUSD = api
                .column( 7 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Total over this page
            pageUZS = api
                .column( 6, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
            // Total over this page
            pageUSD = api
                .column( 7, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(
                totalUZS + ' UZS / SAHIFA ' + pageUZS + ' UZS'
            );
            $( api.column( 7 ).footer() ).html(
                totalUSD + ' USD / SAHIFA ' + pageUSD + ' USD'
            );
        }

    });
```

and this is table header fields

```
<table class="datatables-basic table table-sm table-hover font-small-3" id="docsTable">
                            <thead class="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2">#</th>
                                <th rowspan="2"></th>
                                <th rowspan="2">DOC#</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">SANA</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">HAMKOR</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">TELEFON</th>
                                <th colspan="2" class="text-center">NARXI</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">AMALLAR</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>UZS</th>
                                <th>USD</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
```

Comment: What do you want to get from `replace()`? `/'UZS', 'USD','/` doesn't seem the right regex at all. You are replacing this whole string (if found): `'UZS', 'USD','` with a single dot. This is what your function gains on some random strings from your table: https://codepen.io/cheesyman/pen/ExoQXRK (open the console to see)

Comment: @cheesyMan. That's my problem I'm getting datas [24, 12, 4] how I can get [24000.00, 12000.00, 8000.00] in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work (also notice that, as you're using `parseFloat()`, multiplying `* 1` is redundant):

```
 // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
 var intVal = function ( i ) {
     return typeof i === 'string'
         ? parseFloat(i.replace(/UZS|USD| /g, '').replace(/,/,'.')) //<= please, notice there's a space between USD| and /g
         : typeof i === 'number'
             ? i
             : 0
 }
```

If I can suggest, *nesting ternary operators* quickly gets your code difficult to read. Prefer `if... else...` instead

Comment: Dear @cheesyMan this is perfect. One simple question using your code I'm getting numbers like this [24000, 12000, 8000] how I can get float number [24000.00, 12000.00, 8000.00]?

Comment: As `parseFloat()` turns strings into numbers, there's no way to show a 12000 **number** as 12000.00, because the part  `.00` doesn't makes sense to a number (should be different if you had `.20` or similar, i.e. if there are *significant digits* after the . ). If you want .00 you have to convert back numbers to strings. Take a look at the `Intl.NumberFormat` constructor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat). Obviously, remember to make your calculations and totals **BEFORE** you convert them back to strings :)